# Spark UDF Causing Job Abort

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to do very simple UDF operations on a data frame and I am met with errors

I am working with an example straight from the PySpark API, the only difference is I am using different data (and that mine doesn't work)

Here is my DF:

```
parq.show(3)

+-------------------+---+----------+---------+--------------------+------+--------------+----------------+---------+---------+---------+-------------------+--------+
|  registration_dttm| id|first_name|last_name|               email|gender|    ip_address|              cc|  country|birthdate|   salary|              title|comments|
+-------------------+---+----------+---------+--------------------+------+--------------+----------------+---------+---------+---------+-------------------+--------+
|2016-02-03 07:55:29|  1|    Amanda|   Jordan|    ajordan0@com.com|Female|   1.197.201.2|6759521864920116|Indonesia| 3/8/1971| 49756.53|   Internal Auditor|   1E+02|
|2016-02-03 17:04:03|  2|    Albert|  Freeman|     afreeman1@is.gd|  Male|218.111.175.34|                |   Canada|1/16/1968|150280.17|      Accountant IV|        |
|2016-02-03 01:09:31|  3|    Evelyn|   Morgan|emorgan2@altervis...|Female|  7.161.136.94|6767119071901597|   Russia| 2/1/1960|144972.51|Structural Engineer|        |
+-------------------+---+----------+---------+--------------------+------+--------------+----------------+---------+---------+---------+-------------------+--------+
```

Here is the relevant schema entry:

```
parq.printSchema()
 |-- salary: double (nullable = true)
```

Then doing a simple udf operation to square the salary column

```
square_udf = F.udf(lambda z: z**2, DoubleType())
parq.select(square_udf(F.col("salary"))).show(10)
```

This yields:
`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure ...`

In my mind there is absolutely no reason that it should be doing this, if someone could clarify my thinking that would be great.

Comment: Can you provide a little sample of your `parq` dataframe?

Comment: @Gocht I have updated my post thx

Comment: I have tested your code and no error was raised. That could be due to your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Gocht to testing my code and saying it works. I had nulls in my salary column interfering so I ran this first:

```
parq_nn = parq.select("*").where("salary is not null")
```

And it worked